# Samsung s4 and s3 difference bitmap decodeStream

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

> **SAMSUNG S4**

[image]

> **SAMSUNG S3**
>   [image]

I dowloaded image from website and save them to sd card. When i use samsung s3 everything is normal image is scaled and width is match_parent but when i use samsung s4 image's width is maxmımum this size, i check image width and height when i read from sd card these are same no difference samsung s3 and s4. my code for use to reading image from sd card

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/sample");    
            myDir.mkdirs();

            String fname = "Image_"+ ana.haberBanner.get(position).getId() +".jpg";

            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    try {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            haberResim.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

this code is running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The image seems to be smaller than `ImageView` (S4 has more pixels on the screen). Set an appropriate [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for your `ImageView` (`FIT_XY` should do the trick).

Comment: it is okey for imageview but i am using fancycoverflow for carousel animation image. i tried same thing but not affected :/

Answer (score 0):

it can not be easy that like but it is :/

```
bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bimages2.get(i), dpToPx(340), dpToPx(200), true);
```